# Unwanted overlapping text in watch glance

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch

In my watch glance I have selected the following layout in IB:

[image]

For some unknown reason the two top labels want to overlap...sometimes. Like this:

[image]

My understanding is that it shouldn't be possible to overlap labels using watchkit. Any idea of how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have often found that when labels are not in a Group container, the layout can be unpredictable. I would recommend placing the two top labels in a Group and then make the first Vertical Position Top and the second Vertical Position Bottom. Also be sure to set both labels to use "size to fit content."